# Is it a security risk to store user session tokens in localStorage?

Tags: php, security, session, local-storage, token

I'm designing an authentication system that stores some hashed strings as "tokens" on the client machine

```
localStorage['tokens'] = [username, string1, string2, .... ]
```

and also associates those tokens with a row in a database table

```
____________________________________
| Table: current_user_sessions     |
------------------------------------
| username | token1 | token2 | ... |
```

so that any time a user tries complete an action, the client machine queries the database asking for a row with those matched tokens and the user's name to verify that the user is logged in a valid session.

I send these tokens as variables to the php page that checks to make sure the session is valid.

```
$tokens = $_GET['tokens']
$session_is_valid = query_that_checks_db_for_tokens($tokens)
return $session_is_valid
```

Is it possible for someone to get access to another user's localStorage through an XSS attack and is this an unsafe way to keep a user session secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with this approach is that local storage is vulnerable to XSS since it is accessable via JavaScript (of course, having a page which is vulnerable to XSS is a problem in of itself).  If your tokes are small enough to fit in a cookie, then that is the best place to put them.

If you set the HTTP-only flag on a cookie, the browser will not allow JavaScript to access it.  If you set the Secure flag on a cookie, the browser will only send it with HTTPS requests.  If you are sending security related tokens, you should probably be using both flags.

Comment: What if it doesn't fit into a cookie ? You have no choice other than db and make sure your input is safe as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @jayadev If it doesn't fit in a cookie it's going to be insecure.  The OP is asking if local storage is secure.  The answer is no.  There generally isn't a good argument for storing more **secure** data client side than can be put in a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Your browser protects local storage using the same origin policy, so Javascript code running on a page hosted at `http://a.com` cannot access local storage stored by Javascript code running on a page at `http://b.com`.  If your webpage has an XSS vulnerability and people can inject Javascript code into it, they can access your local storage.

With that being said, your scheme seems reasonable.  Spending a little bit of time to make sure that your page doesn't have any XSS vulnerabilities seems like a good use of time.

Answer (score -1):

You should use cookies if the user data is small (or can be compressed) and fits into a user cookie. That avoids the need for local storage and the security issues that come with it.

If that is not the case then you are forced to use a local/centralized storage, the main items you should be careful is [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) when you read tokens from http parameters and directly use in mysql queries. Typically [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or parametrized queries are used to prevent this (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)). You also should escape your input to prevent [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) independent of your session storage strategy.

Some details to be aware of :

- User name is a unique identifier (some sort of guid).
- A faster way typically used for storing session is using memcached cluster for session data.
- Be aware of [Cross side request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and use crumbs since you are updating user data.

Comment: I would assert that it is, infact, unsafe.  The OP asked if XSS can be used to steal auth tokens stored in local storage and it can.

Comment: Well browsing internet in your computer is potentially unsafe but the solution is not to stop browsing :). As I mentioned in my solution if you can use cookies of course you should, but looking at the schema and amount of data I assume the data is big, or he might have already considered cookie. Then there is no choice other than to use a central storage like a db. The solution is to make sure you inputs are clean.